# Estimating the mean with least median of squares target

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, pattern-recognition, descriptive-statistics

I have a set of real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. I would like estimate the mean of the set, $y$, such that the median of squares will be minimal : $\operatorname{median}(x_i-y)^2$

Is there a closed form formula for this problem or a series of steps to finding $y$? How do I prove it provides the minimum for this function?

To stress out - I'm not estimating really - I need an accurate answer that minimizes the median of the square distances.

Thanks

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet that there is no closed form solution to this problem since it involves sorting. I don't think there is an algorithm involving some fixed number of steps either. However, it would usually be possible to do this using numerical methods.

Here's an example using the Python **scipy** software.

> sample = [ 3, 5, 9, 10, 13, 17, 19, 22 ]
>
> from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
>
> def f ( x ) :
>
> > global sample
> >
> > squ_dist = [ pow ( s - x, 2 ) for s in sample ]
> >
> > if len ( sample ) % 2 == 0 :
> >
> > > return (squ_dist[len(squ_dist)/2]+squ_dist[len(squ_dist)/2+1])*0.5
> >
> > else :
> >
> > > return squ_dist[len(squ_dist)/2]
>
> res = minimize_scalar ( f )
>
> res.x

14.999999999999993

... meaning that 15 would be the estimate for the mean in this sample. The software is using Brent's method of optimisation to get a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for simplicity that $n$ is odd, and let $m=(n+1)/2$; assume also that the values are all distict and sorted. Now, the values $(x_i -y)^2$ have the same ordering as $|x_i -y|$, and problem is equivalent to minimize the median of $|x_i -y|$

Suppose that we pick a tentative $y$. Let $A(y) \subset \{1,2 \cdots n\}$ be the set of indexes of the $m$ nearest neighbours of $y$; let $j \in A(y)$ be the index of the farthest element, so that  $z =|x_j - y|$ is our target value to minimize. In general, we should be able to improve our initial $y$ moving it towards $x_j$, as long as $A(y)$ does not change, nor $j$. $A(y)$ will change when there is a tie, between the farthest and the next-to-farthest element. The minimum must occur at one such point. Then, our search for the minimum must check only $(n+1)/2$ alternatives. Assuming the list is ordered, then:

$$y=\min \frac{x_i+x_{i+m-1}}{2}$$

Two examples

[image]

[image]

What's is left is to attack the even $n$ case, and the case of repeated values.